# Typescript : How to conditionally make a type as optional if it's undefined

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

A function used for navigation take page `name` and `params` as arguments.
We have a type mapping of `page` & it's corresponding `params`

Hence when we use incorrect params during navigation to a page, typescript will point out the error.

But when certain pages do not expect any params(mentioned as undefined),
We cannot navigate to the page with just passing in the page name. We exclusively need to pass `undefined` as the `param`

We want the param `type` to be `optional(?)` when it resolved to `undefined` via the mapping.
If it's made as optional by default, all other page navigations also work without having a param being passed.

````
type RouteParamMapping1 = {
  Page1: string;
  Page2: number;
};

type RouteParamMapping2 = {
  Page3: boolean;
  Page4: string[];
  Page5: undefined;
};

type AllRouteParamMapping = RouteParamMapping1 & RouteParamMapping2;


//function to navigate to a page
function navigate<K extends keyof AllRouteParamMapping>(
  name: K,
  params: AllRouteParamMapping[K],
) {
  console.log(name, params);
}

navigate('Page1', 'Joe');
navigate('Page2', 20);
navigate('Page3', true);
navigate('Page4', ['a', 'b', 'c']);
navigate('Page5'); //This is throwing the typescript error. 
//If the params have resolved to undefined, then it should be valid to just pass the page name

//if we make the navigate func -> params as optional with '?' then we can pass undefined to all other cases as well
// it makes all below as valid, which it shouldn't
// navigate('Page1');
// navigate('Page2');
// navigate('Page3');
// navigate('Page4');
// navigate('Page5');```



If the type resolved to undefined, it should become optional.
````

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wja8lW) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You will need something like overloads for this one

```js
type AllPages = keyof AllRouteParamMapping;
type PagesWithNoParam = keyof FilterUndefined<AllRouteParamMapping>;

type FilterUndefined<T> = {[K in keyof T as undefined extends T[K] ? K : never]: T[K]}

function navigate(name: PagesWithNoParam): void
function navigate<K extends AllPages>(name: K, params: AllRouteParamMapping[K]): void
function navigate(name: AllPages, params?: AllRouteParamMapping[AllPages]) {
  console.log(name, params);
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBASg9gV2BACgQwE5oLYFk1hgCWAdgOYCMUAvFAN4CwAUFFOmRBQFxQDOwGUmQDczVuwgAmHiQTYARhAyimAXxXNQkWImToseAsXKSa9MWzQcAzD3lw4AGwhoSK8VYgAWHv0HkAbQBdd0sOAFYeBBIAEwgAM1IIGNCJADYZOUUMKAAfKGi4xJJklXVmTXBoAEFHR3gkVEwcfEIhMwa9ZsM28ioAMh1G-RajIUkNJi0auoleMwBrCBA4eKha+t0mg1bjEUrtOYB1ImAACwA5OBHsReXVqAAxIkdkDABVWISkmIAeDc621GvTIAD5JtMni83p8ij9fgAVUFmOgBADSUFIUCWKzWCKgaHmhW+JRiUAgAA9kLF5gj0UEoAB+KAYmQQABuSiCPDpaKCqgqTHi0QAxsAiHASFASGh2UQyGhkAAKGXYCA8Y6nS7XboASh47LgRBizGFJDFEqlMrlCuQvwxlOpMXmGzmoJVOHVLIANFAwN1eDwAVsbrshPT9VBDcbTaLxZLpbL5YqIB61UHZp5eL7-QZeIyM5tht0w4FXVmgrrzCwoCLJbwnBAAHSOOBkNMQHMB3VlQXW5PKgDkEgog99g4AUnAIIOe8x+7bU8PPJIx1BJAAGOdMBcppXLmxrgQICDb3dDiReNcBQdoNeD+T3kWDysqc9LiThWdvpOL-fpb951-PcDwgNI1wobdmAAemgqAAAFgF4ABaSlIDFVCMAwOAMCAm0QJHQCmFghCkNQil0OATDsNwndgIvFciJIxCULQiAMKUGi8IHD9PGsJi4JY8jKOonDuL-UCr23IA)

Comment: Overloads are certainly an option but you don't *need* them; see [this version](https://tsplay.dev/wja8lW).  Also (and this isn't clear from the question) I'd think `FilterUndefined` should possibly be made `undefined extends T[K]` instead of `T[K] extends undefined`, since something like `string | undefined` should probably be optional also, right?

Comment: I think you're right about `undefined`. I'm not a fan of your solution. I used it a lot when the syntax landed but I don't like the way tooltips look with it, I don't like that you can't have a distinct JSDoc for each overload, and I'm never sure if an array is actually allocated on the heap or not.

Comment: I wasn’t saying my version was *superior* to overloads (depending on the use case overloads can be good or bad), just that you don’t *need* overloads.

Comment: Oh sure I was just sharing an opinion

Answer (score -2):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you can use "any" which would allow an undefined as well as any other type. If that's not it, good luck!

Comment: It's best to avoid the `any` type wherever possible. Using `any` is essentially opting out of TypeScript's type safety, which rather defeats the point of using TypeScript in the first place. The TypeScript handbook lists "Don't use `any`" in its [Do's and Don'ts](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#any) section.